# Show out-of-stock shopify products at the last page of entire pagination

Tags: pagination, shopify, liquid, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

I am trying to modify the **main-collection-product-grid.liquid** file to show the out-of-stock products to appear at the very end of the pagination on the Shopify collection page. To do that I have separated the products based on availability and ran two different loops.

First, I loop in-stock products, so they appear at top, and then the out-of-stock products which are displayed at the bottom. This works.

`{% assign in_stock_products = collection.products | where: 'available', true %} {% assign out_of_stock_products = collection.products | where: 'available', false %}`

The issue is, the out-of-stock products show up at the end of each page, but I want to show them at the very end of the page.

For example, I have a total 50 products and show 10 products per page. Five of them are out of stock. So, I have a total of 5 pages, and I want to show the out-of-stock product on the last page rather than at the end of each page.

Now, it's showing the out-of-stock products at the end of page 1, but what I am expecting is they should show up at the very last page.

Is it possible to achieve this with liquid?

I tried the following liquid code. It works but shows the out-of-stock products at the end of each pagination page, but I want to show them on the last page.

```
{%- paginate collection.products by 10 -%}

{% assign in_stock_products = collection.products | where: 'available', true %}
{% assign out_of_stock_products = collection.products | where: 'available',
false %}

<!-- Loop through in-stock products -->
{% for product in in_stock_products %} {{ product.title }}
<!-- ... out-of-stock product information ... -->
{% endfor %}

<!-- Loop through out-of-stock products -->
{% for product in out_of_stock_products %} {{ product.title }}
<!-- ... out-of-stck product information ... -->
{% endfor %} {% comment %}

{% endpaginate %}
```